# How can I discover dark pool orders in an order book?

Tags: market-data

I'm learning order flow.  I would like to differentiate between aggregated dark pool volume and aggregated algo trading volume.

Is there a way to tell orders coming from a dark pool from algo orders?

Comment: you have to be more precise on what are you working with. What is your environnment ? your data ?